# Coinbase unauthorized access

Tags: c#, coinbase-api

I'm trying to list my coinbase accounts with the following API `https://api.coinbase.com/`.

I used the following path `GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts`.

I systematically get a reject 'Unauthorized (401) error'

**Below some important checks I have done:**

- My software correctly get ressource which does not require specific authorization level like `/v2/time` for instance
- I have waited 48 hours since my API key creation
- I have set all the privileges on all the accounts (BTC wallet, EUR wallet etc)
- I manage to view my balance on my trading account `https://api.pro.coinbase.com/`

Any ideas ?

```
HttpClient _httpClient


var timeStamp = GetSecondsSinceEpoch();
var signature = ComputeSignature($"{timeStamp}GET/v2/accounts", privateKey);

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "MyAppClient");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-KEY", publicKey);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", timeStamp); 

private static string ComputeSignature(string preHashString, string privateKey)
{
    try
    {
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey)))
        {
            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(preHashString));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

var response = await _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.GetAsync(new Uri("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts"));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

*EDIT*

In fact for access to `GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts`, it seems that we should use OAuth authorization and not API KEY, so it takes the form of :

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer","MyAccessToken")`

Once I have created Oauth access via my Coinbase Main Account, I successfully manage to retrieve my accounts information by using `Invoke-WebRequest` command but I still get  `Unauthorized (401) error`  with the CSharp code equivalent

Comment: Are you sending proper authorization header in the request?

Comment: I'd expect you'd need to include a parameter containing your key in the call - /v2/accounts?key=xxx

Comment: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#list-accounts You need to pass AuthorizationHeader in form `Bearer <<TOKEN>>`

Comment: Best way to solve is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the first request using a browser with https://api.pro.coinbase.com/ with the first request that is failing with c#.  The request has headers and you need to make the headers in c# look exactly like the headers when it works.  You probably need to specify the Content-Type which indicates the default browser to use.